# Outlets in bedroom, top outlet is working, bottom outlet is not

Tags: electrical

I have 4 outlets in one of my bedrooms.  One of the outlets is working with no problem at all both the top and bottom plug work.  The other three outlets in the bedroom, the top outlet works but there is no power going to the bottom outlet.  This has occurred on all 3 separate outlets.  What could be the cause of this, should I be concerned.  I tried resetting the breaker just in case, but that did not work.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is there a wall switch in or near the room whose function you don't know? It may be switching the bottom outlets, for table lamps that can be controlled by that switch.

Comment: No, there is only one light switch in the bedroom that controls the light and it was on.  There is also a ceiling light right outside the bedroom that is no longer working.  I thought it was the bulb, but I replaced the bulb and it is still not working.  I did try the bulb in another lamp to make sure it worked and it did.  I am not sure if the bottom plugs were working before I don't use that room very often.  I am thinking I will need to get an electrician out.  Thanks again

Comment: So is there anyway that you can make it not on switch I have to have my porch light on in order to have bottoms plugs work in living room

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Daniel's comment above about any wall switches in the room with unknown function, I suggest adding one of [these 6-dollar outlet tester tools](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012DHVQ0) to your DIY bag.  Just plug it in and it will diagnose/report many common issues with wall outlet wiring (just in case.)

Note, if you plug one of these into an outlet that is 'switched' by a wall switch somewhere, then the lights will show the 'open hot' condition which is all three lights out. (I know, it's not intuitave: "no-lights means what?")

So you plug it in and leave it in one of the bottom outlets, then go around flipping only one switch at a time until it shows "off-on-on" which signals "correct."

Remember (while it is unlikely) it could be that the lower plugs are wired in 3-way so, continue flipping switches one at a time, just to make sure the plug doesn't go on then off again.

Comment: I am going to pick up one of these on my way home today.